# Are my changes gone after "hg revert"?

Tags: mercurial

After my last commit I wrote a bunch of code. Before committing again, I ran `hg add`. 
It added some files I was not interested in, so I ran

```
$ hg revert --all
```

thinking that all the added files would go away. They did go away, but I also reverted all the code written since the last commit, which means a ton of work was lost! What are my options?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you `hg revert` a file (or `--all` files), Mercurial *saves a backup* of the file under another name. This is to make it harder for you to lose work. If the file was called `foo`, you will have a `foo.orig` with the original version.

You can use

```
$ hg status --all --include "**.orig"
```

to see all the `.orig` files in your working copy. Move the ones you need back, re-add them and commit.

On a related note: people sometimes add the `--no-backup` flag to their `[defaults]` section in order to get rid of the `.orig` files Mercurial scatter around. I think this a really bad idea... just ignore the `.orig` files instead by adding

```
syntax: glob
*.orig
```

to your `.hgignore` file. That's much safer and one day you'll be happy that you have these `.orig` file lying around :-)

Comment: When you "move the ones you need back, re-add them and commit" should you rename foo.txt.orig to foo.txt manually for each file, or is there a better way?

Comment: How do you "move the file back"?

Comment: @Green, you `mv foo.orig foo` for each file `foo.orig` that you want restore.